# property or indexer cannot be assigned to it is read only in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting property or indexer 'en.AdmitLocalTime cannot be assigned to--- it is read only.
Can anyone suggest me how to set this value?

Class

```
 public DateTime? AdmitDTUTC { 
    get { return admitDTUTC; } 
    set 
    { 
        if (value != null) admitDTUTC = value.Value; 
    } 
}
public string AdmitLocalTime { 
    get 
    { 
        if(!admitDTUTC.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)) 
            return admitDTUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
        else 
            return ""; 
    } 
}

while (reader.Read())
{
                        
     en.AdmitDTUTC = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("AdmitDTUTC"));
     en.AdmitLocalTime = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("AdmitLocalTime")); // Getting error
                        
}
```

Comment: You haven't written a setter for `AdmitLocalTime`, write one and your code will compile.

Comment: the localtime is just formatting the admitDTUTC time so doesn't have a setter. Set the AdmitDUTC time and it will change what the local time is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the property setter is not defined so the error.

Comment: I don't think there should be a setter. It is means to be a read only property to show the localtime of AdminDTUTC. So the answer is you shouldn't be trying to set the local time - just set AdmitDTUTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string AdmitLocalTime {
        get
        {
            if(!admitDTUTC.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)) 
                return admitDTUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
            else return "";
        } 
    }
```

As you can see in the code above, `AdmitLocalTime` has only a getter (via `get`) and no setter (`set`) making this property a *read-only* property as it is said by compiler error.

To solve this - you need add `set` method

example:

```
    private DateTime admitDTLocal;
    
    public string AdmitLocalTime {
        get
        {
            if(!admitDTUTC.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)) 
                return admitDTUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
            else return "";
        }
        set
        {
            admitDTLocal = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

or with string field..

```
    private string admitDTLocal;

    public string AdmitLocalTime {
        get
        {
            if(!admitDTUTC.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)) 
                return admitDTUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
            else return "";
        }
        set
        {
            admitDTLocal = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TheGeneral ok)

Comment: @MickyD yes, it is pretty self-explanatory, but it still have sense to tell "what exactly this error means" :)

Comment: The get on both examples here return the local time string from admitDTUTC, so the set isn't actually changing anything except stopping an error message (and setting admitDTLocal ) that isn't accessable).

Answer (score 0):

AdmitLocalTime is a read only property, and just gets the localtime equivalent of AdmitDTUTC.

So, you shouldn't be directly trying to set the localtime. It is controlled by setting the AdmitDTUTC.